# Jenkins pipeline to call SonarQube code coverage for node.js project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I am  trying to do code coverage for node js project via Jenkins,  I’ve one doubt that where to add the “sonar-project.properties” file, it in root repository that means in sonar-scanner installed repository or in the jenkins path i.e. “/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/”,

can some help to fix this I’m getting error while executing the pipeline.

Error log as follows:

- /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/sonardemo/bin/sonar-scanner
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demosonar@tmp/durable-f32cf5e2/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/sonardemo/bin/sonar-scanner: not found
  [Pipeline] }
  WARN: Unable to locate ‘report-task.txt’ in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?

Comment: You can place the sonar.properties file inside the root directory of the node.js project.

Comment: Yes. already i have added the file. still it is throwing error.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked the error. This is the main error, `sonar-scanner is not found`. Can you check the permission whether jenkins user has correct permission to execute sonar-scanner as it is not able to find `sonar-scanner` in the path.

Comment: have enabled permission.  still it shows permission denied issue for Jenkins work space.